# Lyapunov equation, uniqueness, stability.

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

With respect to $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$, and $u=-Kx(t)$, and $K=R^{-1}B^{\rm T}P$, where P solution of $\tilde{A}^{\rm T}P+P\tilde{A}+Q+PBR^{-1}B^{\rm T}P$, where  $\tilde{A}=A-BK$.

I believe that, for a given $A, B, Q, R$,  the optimal control $u^*$, in terms of the solution $P$ of the algebraic ricati equation,  $A^{\rm T}P+PA+Q-PBR^{-1}B^{\rm T}P$ is unique.

I know that, for the given system, there exists several $K_i$, $i=1,2,\dotsc$ that stabilizes the system. My confusion is do each of all those $i$ number of $K$s also should meet a Lyapunov equation such as  $\tilde{A}_i^{\rm T}P+P\tilde{A}_i+Q+PBR^{-1}B^{\rm T}P$, where $\tilde{A}=A-BK_i$? as they are stabilizing.

I know that $P$ matrix that is solution of Lyapunov equation stabilizes the closed-loop. Does it implies that all the $P$ matrices, that makes the system stable should meet a Lyapunov equation?

Is it that the $P$ matrix that represents optimal control is unique and meets algebraic Ricati equation and other stationarity conditions for optimality.  ?

And the $P$ matrices that stabilizes the system just meets a Lyapunov equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyapunov's theorem guarantees that any full state feedback gain $K$ for which $\dot{x} = (A-BK)x$ is *globally asymptotically stable* must also satisfy a Lyapunov equation. E.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). For a system to be GAS we must have some $x_e\in X$, where $X$ is the state space for the system $\dot{x} = f(x)$, for which $f(x_e) = 0$ *and* $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t) = x_e$ for any path $x(t)$. Since the typical LTI stability criterion (e.g. $\mathfrak{Re}\{\lambda\}< 0$ for all $\lambda \in\Lambda(A-BK)$) is equivalent to GAS for LTI systems (e.g. see [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~byao/Research/Supplements/Lyapunov.pdf)), then there are unique pairs of positive, symmetric matrices $P_i,Q_i$ for which $A-BK_i$ obeys a Lyapunov equation for each $K_i$ for which $A-BK_i$ is stable in the typical LTI sense.

> I know that $P$ matrix that is solution of Lyapunov equation stabilizes the closed-loop. Does it implies that all the $P$ matrices, that makes the system stable should meet a Lyapunov equation?

Yes, but $P$ is a unique $P_i$ for each $K_i$.

> Is it that the $P$ matrix that represents optimal control is unique and meets algebraic Ricati equation and other stationarity conditions for optimality. ?

Generally obeying a Ricatti equation is not synonymous with obeying a Lyapunov equation--the first is an optimality constraint, the second is a stability constraint. In fact, they only case of equivalence I can think of is LQR/LQG problems where the Lyupinov function happens to be a quadratic form similar to the integrand of the optimization functional.

> And the $P$ matrices that stabilizes the system just meets a Lyapunov equation?

There is a unique $P_i$ which stabilizes the system which is also the unique solution to the Lyapunov equation for that system.

Comment: Yes "Obeying a Ricatti equation is not synonymous to obeying a Lyapunov equation". That is the key point. Thank you. And in the LQR case, where the cost to be minimized is quadratic, Lyapunov equation is equivalent to Ricatti equation. I have read several versions of these sentences but I failed to understand some concepts. All Ricatti equations are Lyapunov equations, but vice versa does not hold. right?

Comment: @user252783 I'm not sure what is saying "all Ricatti equations are Lyapunov equations". As I said, they have to do with totally different properties of the system--optimality vs. stability. Perhaps you can argue this must practically be the case, since a reasonable optimization functional will also force the system to be stable (again, you can think of the LQR case) but there is no *mathematical* reason I'm aware of that lets you make this association *a priori*.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer without details. But you will find your answer in the following slides.

You can start reading from slide 10 of the first slide set.

http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/~sc4160/download/hs_slides_chapter_4.pdf
http://www.dcsc.tudelft.nl/~sc4160/download/hs_slides_chapter_5.pdf